# php: How can I make a nested post work in another

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to click on the "A" button Then display the "Submit" button to click on it to display "ok"

the first post is ok but the second doesn't work

when I click on the button "submit" nothing happens and it disappears

```
<?php   
         function createtab() {
?>
         <form id="#form" action="#v_form"  method="post" >
        <input  type="submit" name="fooo" value="A" />
         </form>  
<?php


        if ( isset( $_POST["fooo"] ) ) {
 ?>

    <form id="form" action="#form" method="post">  
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">  
    </form> 
<?php   
    if( isset( $_POST["Submit"] ) ) {

      print("ok");

    } 

    }  


    }
?>
```

Comment: Its inside a function, so its dependant on the fact that you having called that function first. But it will fail none the less, because your first form data will not be present when the second form gets submitted.

Comment: Please do not [repost your same question multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110274/ifset-on-submit-not-working-in-php-code).

Comment: Please post you questions in english

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ifset" on Submit not working in php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110274/ifset-on-submit-not-working-in-php-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include a hidden input with the name 'fooo' as such to have the isset($_POST['fooo']) true for the second form to have it continue to show. Please see my sample code below just as an example:

```
function first_form() {
    echo '<form id="#form" action="#v_form"  method="post" >
    <input  type="submit" name="fooo" value="A" />
    </form>';
}

function second_form() {
    echo '<form id="form" action="#form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="fooo" value="A">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>';
}

if (isset($_POST['fooo'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo 'OK';
    }
    second_form();
} else {
    first_form();
}
```